# Converting array of arrays into flattened dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Got a pandas dataframe with the below structure

```
0    [{'review_id': 4873356, 'rating': '5.0'}, {'review_id': 4973356, 'rating': '4.0'}]
1    [{'review_id': 4635892, 'rating': '5.0'}, {'review_id': 4645839, 'rating': '3.0'}] 
....
....
```

I would like to flatten into a dataframe with the following columns review_id and rating

I was trying out `pd.DataFrame(df1.values.flatten())` but looks like I'm getting something basic not right, need help!!!

Comment: How to recreate the original dataframe?

Comment: This is the original json
{
  "status": true,
  "total_reviews": 323,
  "data": [
    {
      "review_id": 4873356,
      "rating": "5.0"
    },
    {
      "review_id": 4854192,
      "rating": "5.0"
    },
    {
      "review_id": 4848567,
      "rating": "5.0"
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wind up getting an array of lists of dicts so need:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame([x for y in df1.values for x in y])

  rating  review_id
0    5.0    4873356
1    4.0    4973356
2    5.0    4635892
3    3.0    4645839
```

Or if willing to use `itertools`:

```
from itertools import chain

pd.DataFrame(chain.from_iterable(df1.values.ravel()))
```

Answer (score 2):

1st [unnesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-do-i-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe/53218939#53218939) , then re build your dataframe (assuming you have columns name 0)

```
pd.DataFrame(unnesting(df,[0])[0].values.tolist())
Out[61]: 
  rating  review_id
0    5.0    4873356
1    4.0    4973356
2    5.0    4635892
3    3.0    4645839
```

---

```
def unnesting(df, explode):
    idx=df.index.repeat(df[explode[0]].str.len())
    df1=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({x:np.concatenate(df[x].values)} )for x in explode],axis=1)
    df1.index=idx
    return df1.join(df.drop(explode,1),how='left')
```