# flatten array of arrays json object column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, json, pandas

```
0    [{'review_id': 4873356, 'rating': '5.0'}, {'review_id': 4973356, 'rating': '4.0'}]
1    [{'review_id': 4635892, 'rating': '5.0'}, {'review_id': 4645839, 'rating': '3.0'}]
```

I have a situation where I want to flatten such json as solved here: [Converting array of arrays into flattened dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54636542/converting-array-of-arrays-into-flattened-dataframe)

But I want to create new columns so that the output is:

```
review_id_1  rating_1  review_id_2  rating_2
4873356       5.0      4973356      4.0 
4635892       5.0      4645839      3.0
```

Any help is highly appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
print(pd.DataFrame(s.apply(lambda x: {a: b for i in [{x + str(i): y for x, y in v.items()} for i, v in enumerate(x, 1)] for a, b in i.items()}).tolist()))
```

Output:

```
  rating1 rating2  review_id1  review_id2
0     5.0     4.0     4873356     4973356
1     5.0     3.0     4635892     4645839
```

Answer (score 1):

This type of data munging tends to be manual.

```
# Sample data.
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'json_data': [
        [{'review_id': 4873356, 'rating': '5.0'}, {'review_id': 4973356, 'rating': '4.0'}],
        [{'review_id': 4635892, 'rating': '5.0'}, {'review_id': 4645839, 'rating': '3.0'}],
    ]
})

# Data transformation:
# Step 1: Temporary dataframe that splits data from `df` into two columns.
df2 = pd.DataFrame(zip(*df['json_data']))  
# Step 2: Use a list comprehension to concatenate the records from each column so that the df now has 4 columns.
df2 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame.from_records(df2[col]) for col in df2], axis=1)
# Step 3: Rename final columns
df2.columns = ['review_id_1', 'rating_1', 'review_id_2', 'rating_2']
>>> df2
   review_id_1 rating_1  review_id_2 rating_2
0      4873356      5.0      4635892      5.0
1      4973356      4.0      4645839      3.0
```

Comment: Thanks alex.. did you try U10's solution below? looks much more elegant.. cheers..